# Using data table or dplyr instead of loops

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, datatable

Here I have the code with a for loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(mc_1$code))
{cmc1 = mc_1$code[i]
cmc2 = mc_1[mc_1$code == cmc1,]
cmc3 = cmc2[order(cmc2[ ,2], cmc2[ ,3]),]
mc_1[mc_1$code == cmc1,]$region = last(cmc3$region)
}
```

For each value in the variable "code", mc_1 have different number of rows. And mc_1 also has columns of year and month (column 2 and 3), and another column, say, region. "region" is different even for same "code" at different month and year.

For each "code", I want to select only the most recent region by month and year (that's why I use "`order`") and assign that region to all the regions in all the rows for that certain code.

I did have this for loop, which works. But for efficiency and code length issue, how can I rewrite it better using  something like data table or dplyr?

Comment: it would be great if you could supply us with some samle data aswell

Answer (score 1):

you can try this using the dplyr package 
and the fact that `n()` returns the number of rows in each group

```
mc_1 %>% 
  group_by(code) %>% 
  arrange(year, month ) %>% 
  mutate(region = region[n()])
```

hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! First, is it the same to use `mc_1$code` vs only `code` (and also for other variables) here? If I put without the dollar sign, I tried to run it can work but I checked it won't return a unique region for a unique code. And if I run it with every variable like `mc_1$code`, it returns an error "Column `x1$Regional == x1$Regional[n()]` must be length 4 (the group size) or one, not 42035". By the way I think the last line you should use double equal sign? (`mutate(region == region[n()])`)

Comment: By the way, I have other columns in the data, but i just want to change the region for each code, using the most recent region

Comment: It seems i got it worked this way: `mc_1 = arrange(group_by(mc_1, code), year, month)
mc_1 = mutate(mc_1, region = region[n()])`

Comment: @Ian The nice part of dplyr  is that you dont need to use the `$` notation but can access the columns directly within the functions. Therefore you don't need to use `mc_1$code` any more.

Comment: Thanks! I got it worked but i don't know why your solution does not really work. btw i don't like using the pipe haha